# Do I need to add the files who are hosted on CDN inside in manifest file HTML 5 manifest file for offline caching?

Tags: jquery, html, offlineapps, offline-caching, offline-browsing

Do I need to add the files who are hosted on CDN inside in manifest file  for offline caching?

This a example maniefest file

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#This is a comment

CACHE
index.html
style.css

NETWORK:
search.php
login.php

FALLBACK:
/api offline.html
```

But in my project I'm using some files which are hosted on cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
```

How to include these cdn files in manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#appcache) you can't include these files because they are not same origin as manifest file.

> The manifest
>
> This is the resource corresponding to the URL that was given in a
>   master entry's html element's manifest attribute. The manifest is
>   fetched and processed during the application cache download process.
>   All the master entries have the **same origin** as the manifest.

Comment: so the only way to run application offline using hosted file on my own server

Comment: Generally reading spec with more patience it seems it may be possible - same origin restriction may relate only to NETWORK and FALLBACK and https in CACHE. Just correct "CACHE:" (colon) and append lines with absolute URLs after it. Just check if it works then I will reedit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you cannot.  According to the W3C documentation all cached content must satisfy the same origin policy.  You can read all about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html) among other places.